# jQuery(document).width() doesn't include width outside of viewable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`jQuery(document).width()` doesn't include the total width (viewable + outside of viewable when there's a horizontal bar). It equals `jQuery(window).width()`. I thought `jQuery(window).width()` is the viewable area width and `jQuery(document).width()` is the total width.

How do I get the total width or how do I get the width of the area outside of the viewable area using jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work correctly in this test -- http://jsbin.com/ozoge4/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the width of the "invisible" portion, simply subtract the total document width from the visible window width:

```
jQuery(document).width() - jQuery(window).width()
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/D8mAE/)**

[image]

---

Like you write, `$(document).width()` is the total width, and `$(window).width()` is the width that is currently visible.

Tested in the latest Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari.

Comment: I used a ruler. $(document).width() reported the same width as what the ruler showed, which was the the width of the visible window. Then there's an extra portion outside the visible area which I can bring in using the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Tony - Can you provide a picture? I don't understand what the extra portion is? ---- Are you referring to the padding and margin, the chrome of the browser, the width of the vertical scroll bar, or something else?

Comment: The document width is wider than the visible window. Therefore there's a horizonal bar showing. The part of the document which is not showing which is to the right of the window is what I call invisible. You bring it in into view when you drag the bar to the right. That's the width I want to get. The document part which is larger than the window/viewport.

Comment: @Tony - Edited. Just subtract the total width from the visible width to get the width of the document that is not visible.

Comment: @Tony - Did you see my screenshots (I show the scroll bar)? Am I understanding you?

Comment: It was all my mistake. See my answer. I will accept yours for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a jQuery equivalent, but

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].offsetWidth
```

should give the correct width of the page, regardless of window size.

Comment: Same as $(document).width() or $('body').width()

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake. I was displaying the width and then was code somewhere after that that was adjusting the width of some elements, which caused the document to be wider.

Comment: Hehe. Shit happens, these mistakes are always hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

I think this codes are useful as well:

```
self.innerWidth && (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) && document.body.clientWidth;
```