# DOMWindow popup auto resize to contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, popup

I'm using JQuery and learning as I go, I was just curious is there a way to have a DOMwindow auto resize to its content?

I managed to figure out how to change the parameters to take % width and height instead of px but I'm finding that a dynamic resizing view would utilize my site's purpose better.

Should I be looking into a different type of code to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: Is the new window loading scripts, css, etc that you have control of?

Answer (score 0):

If you had a containing wrap element, which holds all of the content, and is not set to 100%:

```
<div id="main_container">
    // page contents
</div>
```

You could now get the dimensions of the containing element and then resize your window to suit.

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myElement = $('#main_container');
    var sWidth = myElement.width();
    var sHeight = myElement.height();

    window.resizeTo(sWidth, sHeight);
})
```

There are other ways of doing this, if you search thoroughly on this website, you will find your answer. You can use `(document).width()` and `(window).width()`, as this answer describes: [jQuery(document).width() doesn't include width outside of viewable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722886/jquerydocument-width-doesnt-include-width-outside-of-viewable-area)